# Imbalanced multiclass classification using company names

Tags: neural-network, nlp, text-classification, multiclass-classification, fasttext

I have this classification scenario below in which Im getting a very low F1, precision, recall and other metrics.

1. Target is multiclass (about ~200 classes) which is highly imbalanced
2. I only use company names as classifier (mostly 1-2 words which have max of 8 words), no other fields (like description, etc.)
3. Training data ~ 100k+ records
4. Preprocessing: numeric and special characters and stopwords removal
5. I have very low resources for processing (thats why when I try to use oversampling techniques like smote, distance_smote for multiclass, etc., I always get memory error)
6. Tried using different vectorization/embedding/tokenizer like word2vec, tfidf, fasttext, bert, roberta, etc. but to no avail
7. Tried using (and fine-tuning) different algorithms (networks, svm, trees, boosting, etc.) but also getting low scores.
8. I also did cost-sensitive learning (using class weights) but it only decreased my scores.

Tried all options that I know but scores are not increasing. Can you recommend other options here or do you think any part of the process that may be wrong/discarded? Thank you!

Distribution of target labels:
[image: Distribution of target labels]

Sample observations
[image: Sample observations]

Comment: Can you share just a little sample of your data, to better figure out the problem?

Comment: Hi @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87 , already added images (distribution of labels and sample records) in the problem. Thank you!

Comment: According to you, can the system learn the relation between text and labels using the training data? Is it feasible for a human to perform this task? From the little information I have, it seems a quite difficult task.

Comment: Hmm does this mean that I cant do anything about it and move on (maybe gather data other than company names)? Or am I missing something in my process or I need to discard something? @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87

Comment: Gather significant data other than company names could be relevant, I think.

Comment: For future reference, non-programming questions should not be asked on SO, rather https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Also note that when you do 200-way classification, the random baseline would obtain only 0.005% accuracy. Even with good data, this would be a really hard problem to solve.

Comment: Also for yours @Erwan. Would just like to know how did you compute the 0.005% baseline accuracy?

Comment: for the random baseline we assume that classifier picks a class randomly, so with 200 classes it has 1/200 chances to be correct = 0.005. For the majority baseline we assume that it always predicts the largest class, which gives as accuracy the proportion of this class.

Answer (score 2):

There is essentially no way to know that 'Exxon' is an oil company, and 'Apple' a computer company, and 'McDonalds' a fast-food chain, just from their company names.

Even if you have a list of every other company in the world, by name and type, that's not enough to make the deduction for these last 3. Only other outside info – like a few sentences about them, or other data – could classify them.

In fact, while company names sometimes describe their exact field-of-commerce, often they're totally arbitrary, as that gives them more freedom to range over many products/services, or create their own unique associations with the name (aka branding).

So I strongly suspect your (unshown) names & (unshown) labels are just too arbitrary for the data you're using to get very good at the task you're attempting.

Is there a real-world situation where someone will *only* have a company name – no other info, or research options – and benefit from correctly guessing the class? If so, more specifics about the situation might help generate more specific tactical recommendations. But mainly such recommendations will be: get richer data about the targets of the classification.

You *might* squeeze a little more out of vague trends in corporate naming via better preprocessing/feature-extraction. You may *want* to keep numbers, special-characters, & punctuation in some form, as they might include extra slight hints. Using subwords (character n-grams) might also reveal some shared word-roots used even in made-up names.

Comment: yes youre correct. I really have the option to add data like description, etc but Im trying if this works. Anyways, thanks for letting me know. Thank you also for the preprocessing tip!